# Sent a file from backend to frontend. Cannot restore its old form

Tags: angular7

here I have a function that reacts to a button click
and gains a file from my backend.

```
onDownload() {

this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/backend/invoice/1/download',
  {responseType: 'blob'})
  .subscribe(res =>
  console.log(res))



}
```

So far, I am happy because inside the chrome console I dont get any errors.
The response looks like this in the console:
[image]

The return type of the Java backend was InputStream (method annotation @Produces(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))

Then I found
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blob-file-download?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

and looked at ngOnInit() in app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
const data = 'some text';
const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

this.fileUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));


}
```

Currently, I think my frontend receives a blob.
So, I can start in the line starting with "this.fileUrl="
and input my blob.

Inside the .html, I have a button to start the onDownload() function
and another tag to save the file on my local hard drive.

```
<div>


<button (click)="onDownload()">Herunterladen</button>
</div>

<a [href]="safeResourceUrl" download="file.txt">DownloadFile</a>
```

Meanwhile, I change the onDownload() method to

```
onDownload() {

    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/backend/invoice/1/download',
      {responseType: 'blob'})
      .subscribe(res => this.safeResourceUrl=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(res)))

  }
```

After I click "Herunterladen" and then the DownloadFile link I get either
a .txt file that I cannot read
[image]

or, if I change the file name to .pdf in the a tag inside the .html,
I get a "failed to load pdf document"

All I want is to get my original pdf that I stored in my database and that was sent from the backend.

Has anyone had the same problem before? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my function to

```
onDownload() {
    window.open(`http://localhost:8080/backend/invoice/${this.invoice.invoiceNr}/download`, 'blank');
  }
```

Now it works:)